# How do I call the specific cell on visual basic 2010(vb.net) datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I wanna call the specific cells on my datagridview for example on inventory. when the stocks is got zero or negative I want to turn specific cells into red. to make it more noticeable.. Thanks for advance guys. Anyway I am using Built in database.